# SMTP mail with encrypt permission Outlook

Tags: c#, smtpclient, mailmessage

When I send a mail with the option "Encrypt only" in Outlook
[image]

I receive a mail like this :

[image]

Currently, I use SMTPClient with MailMessage to send mail :

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = from;
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(destString);
message.To.Add(to);
message.Subject = subject;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

How can I modify my code to send a mail and receive it as the mail above ?

After some researching, I found a solution by using Interop but I can't use it in my project.

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
item.To = abc@gmail.com;
item.Subject = "test";
item.Permission = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlPermission.olDoNotForward;
item.PermissionService = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlPermissionService.olWindows;
item.Send();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand Outlook puts the message in a secure server (Office 365 in my case) and sends the recipient a link to open that message.

It is stated in [this url](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encrypt-email-messages-373339cb-bf1a-4509-b296-802a39d801dc#:%7E:text=Encrypt%20a%20single%20message,message%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Send.), this feature is only for some licenses.

> Microsoft 365 Message Encryption is part of the Office 365 Enterprise E3 license. Additionally, the Encrypt-Only feature (the option under the Encrypt button) is only enabled for subscribers (Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise users) that also use Exchange Online.

I cannot find an API or library documentation, but you should try to communicate with your MS representative about this, so they can provide more information.